# Background code runs on any popup click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get login code in background page to run only once on browser start. But it seems global code in bgpage runs every time on popup clicked. Also it runs in different scope. Is it possible to solve this?

```
// background.js
var someCustomType = new SomeCustomType();

function SomeCustomType() {
  this.firstProperty;
}

function thisShouldBeCalledOnce() {
  someCustomType.firstProperty = 'defined';
  alert('someCustomType.firstProperty=' + someCustomType.firstProperty);
  console.log('thisShouldBeCalledOnce');
}

if (true) {
  // Alwase 'undefined'
  alert('someCustomType.firstProperty=' + someCustomType.firstProperty);
  thisShouldBeCalledOnce();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple code example:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**: just some dummy code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p> sometext</p>
    <button type="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js:**

```
var someCustomType = new SomeCustomType();
function SomeCustomType() {
  this.firstProperty;
}
function thisShouldBeCalledOnce() {
  someCustomType.firstProperty = 'defined';
  alert('someCustomType.firstProperty=' + someCustomType.firstProperty);
  console.log('thisShouldBeCalledOnce');
}
thisShouldBeCalledOnce();
```

In this case, alert was fired once, when you load your extension, when you open popup no alert will be shown. Regards.

Comment: True, I found my bug, `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>` was in `popup.html`